# Selenium headless browser - can't exit without AttributeError-Exception

Tags: python, selenium

Everything's working fine with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs', service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'])
driver.get('https://myurl.com')
```

Now I am working with this page, everything is working quite fine, until I'm finished and I want to terminate the session with the following command:

```
driver.quit()
```

After doing this, Python throws this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Public/Python/changedet/changedet.py", line 20, in <module>
    elba.elba(3)
  File "/home/pi/Public/Python/changedet/listener/elba.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.performCheck();
  File "/home/pi/Public/Python/changedet/listener/elba.py", line 70, in performCheck
    driver.quit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 76, in quit
    self.service.stop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 162, in stop
    self.process.terminate()
AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'terminate'
```

I would be more than happy if anybody knows how to get rid of this exception.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.7.9

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a hard time setting this up. Don't know about the specific error but I got it to work using a virtual display to fake the "head" in Ubuntu 14.

This worked for me:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(2000, 1600))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://google.com")

display.stop()
driver.quit()
```

Kind of hacky, but worth a try.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your comment, just tried it but it still gave me the same error :/

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Comment: Sry, first timer in stackoverflow. Maybe I should have written a comment. Cheers.